# Using hide/show - on element at the time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm using php and jquery to print out articles on my webpage. And I want to be able to use show/hide jquery on one article at the time. As it is right now, when I press hide or show all `<article>` elements in my foreach loop is effected.

HTML and PHP code

```
<section class='col-md-8'> <!-- Div for content, images etc. -->


<?php

$page = new CMS();
$gp = $page->getPage();


 foreach ($gp as $sp) {
  //var_dump($sp);

  echo "<div id='pub'>";
  echo "<h4>" . $sp['title'] . "</h4>"; 
  echo "<article id='pub_art'>" . $sp['content'] . "</article>";  
  echo "<p>" . $sp['created'] . "</p>"; 
  echo "<p>". $sp['writer'] ."</p>";
  echo "<button id='hide'>Hide</button>";
  echo "<button id='show'>Show</button>";
  echo "</div>";

}
?>

</section>
```

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("article").hide();
    });
        $("#show").click(function(){
            $("article").show();
        });
 });
```

CSS

```css
  #pub_art {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: none;

 }
```

Comment: try this `$(document).on("click","#hide",function(){
        $("article").toggle();
    });`

Comment: how would that work @guradio?, the `$("article")` selector takes every single article, instead of just one

Comment: what is `article` `class` or `id`

Comment: @mackeemackee did you try the comment i gave?buti you will be using one button only though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first of all, you're using the same id multiple times, changes these to class instead (as id's can only be used once, and classes can be used multiple times). like this:

```
$output = '';
foreach($gp as $sp){
    $output .= "<div class='pub'>";
        $output .= "<h4>" . $sp['title'] . "</h4>"; 
        $output .= "<article class='pub_art'>" . $sp['content'] . "</article>";  
        $output .= "<p>" . $sp['created'] . "</p>"; 
        $output .= "<p>". $sp['writer'] ."</p>";
        $output .= "<button class='hide'>Hide</button>";
        $output .= "<button class='show'>Show</button>";
    $output .= "</div>";
}
echo $output;
```

As you can see i've concatenated every single echo into one variable and echo it all at once, which is a better aproach (performance wise)

now for the javascript, you're selecting every single `article` tag, instead of this we're gonna look for the sibling `article` which is inside the same div as the `hide` or `show` class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hide").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('article').hide();
    });

    $(".show").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('article').show();
    });
});
```

And your CSS (now also with the class selector)

```
.pub_art {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but my hide button is gone :P it disapears when i change it from id to class?

Comment: Now that's spooky, when you inspect the element, can you see its html?

Comment: Yes i can see it in then

Comment: does it have a `display: none;` or something like that in its css properties?

Comment: Bootstrap was the problem! :)

Comment: Glad you found it :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are producing invalid markup with php with having same ids for multiple instances of elements, so change the attribute `id` to  `class`:

```
<?php
  $page = new CMS();
  $gp = $page->getPage();


 foreach ($gp as $sp) {
  //var_dump($sp);

    echo "<div class='pub'>"; // <-----here
    echo "<h4>" . $sp['title'] . "</h4>"; 
    echo "<article class='pub_art'>" . $sp['content'] . "</article>"; //<---here 
    echo "<p>" . $sp['created'] . "</p>"; 
    echo "<p>". $sp['writer'] ."</p>";
    echo "<button class='hide'>Hide</button>"; // <------here
    echo "<button class='show'>Show</button>"; // <------here
    echo "</div>";
  }
?>
```

css:

```
.pub article.pub_art {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    display: none;
 }
```

Now you can use this script to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hide, .show").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings("article").toggle(this.className === 'show');
    });
 });
```

The `.hide` and `.show` buttons are siblings of the element then you just need to use `.siblings()` to access the its sibling article as they all are been wrapped inside a div `.pub`.

Comment: jai are the button dynamically added or not?

Comment: Just like the answer above it works, but my hide button dissapears? Its gone fro the moment i change it to a class

Answer (score 0):

You can ask Jquery to hide the first article above the element clicked by doing so :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $(this).prev("article").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $(this).prev("article").show();
    });
 });
```

However i suggest you to change your PHP so that it generate unique IDs in order to create valid HTML.